# Can I get value counts for each element in a particular column in a pandas dataframe if the column is a list of multiple strings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, summarization

I have a column called 'tags' in my pandas dataframe that is a list of multiple strings.

```
[abc, 123, xyz]
[456, xyz, 123]
```

Please let me know if there is a way for me to get value counts for this column so the output comes out to be

```
abc 1
123 2
xyz 2
456 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another suggestion

```
pd.Series(df['tags'].sum()).value_counts()
```

Comment: got it! Thank you so much!

Comment: @AnishaAlluru you're welcome! I kindly ask you to upvote my answer if you found it useful, or to accept it if I answered your question

Answer (score 0):

add two list together and then use collections.Counter()